# Does Azure Monitor publish alerts to an RSS Feed or Message Queue or Topic? Can we create a subscription model to receive the alerts themselves?

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

Does Azure Monitor publish alerts(Not Notifications) to an RSS Feed or Message Queue or Topic? Can we create a subscription model to receive the alerts themselves(Not Notifications)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure provides a [unified Alerts system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-overview) that allows defining rules that trigger on a variety of events and conditions. I don't believe these are published by default, but you can integrate through email, webhooks, and other avenues to receive the alerts.